# Cron tab on linux

Tags: cron

I have an .exe setup to run every 5 minutes.It creates a file.

I have stored the users email in a mysql database. The file that get created is named after the primary key of the database.For example:

```
1.txt,2.txt,50.txt etc
```

Where 1,2,and 50 are the primary keys.

I was wondering if there was a way after the cron ran to email the users.I use php on my server.Is there some way to do this?

EDIT:
I think I can rather just set up a .php file to run on cron and use exec().

Comment: rather than creating the files, just email them from whatever script you are using to create the files, or as well as.

Comment: Not really sure how I could email from a c++ .exe anyways.

Comment: I think I can just instead run a .php file on cron and call the .exe from that .php file.

Comment: Are you actually running .exe files on Linux or are you meaning to say *executable* instead of *.exe*? The latter typically refers to a win32 binary, not a generic executable.

Comment: Yeah I meant executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your crontab, you can have cron entries and you can have environment variables. There is a variable called `MAILTO` that specifies the user that will receive the email containing any stdout or stderr from the processed jobs.
To send email to vivek@nixcraft.in, enter:

```
MAILTO=vivek@nixcraft.in
```

If MAILTO is defined but empty (MAILTO=""), no mail will be sent.

```
MAILTO=""
```

The default (if `MAILTO` is not set) is to email the local user who owns the crontab being executed.

I haven't tried it, but you may be able to set the email for just one of your cronjobs using something like this:

```
0 0 * * * /root/daily_task.sh #will email crontab owner
MAILTO=joe@gmail.com
0 1 * * * /root/other_daily_task.sh # will email joe@gmail
MAILTO=root
0 * * * * /root/hourly_task.sh #(hopefully) mails root and not joe
```

Anything after a `#` on a line is of course a comment.

Taken from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-crontab-change-mailto-settings/

Comment: I need to be able to mail the users from the MYSQL database.Would this be able to do it.

Comment: No. These addresses are hard-coded into the crontab. You would not want to try dynamically modifying the tab either. You should add the dynamic destination address stipulation to your question. so a more appropriate answer can be found. However, I think you need to have an entry like `0 0 * * * /path/to/cpp-bin param | /path/to/php-mailer`. This will allow your `php-mailer` script to pull data from the database and send an email based on `cpp-bin`'s output (which is `php-mailer`'s stdin).

Comment: It might even be a good idea to close or delete this question and create an entirely new one with specific details on your goals and limitations